# Querying different endpoints

Tags: angular, rxjs, user-roles

I'm struggling to implement a function in TypeScript & RxJs that returns Observable of data from backend. I need to query differnt endpoints based on user roles. I'm using angular-JWT for authentication. I have two questions:

1. Currently the code compiles nicely, yet the second pair of requests keeps getting cancelled. Why?
2. Is there a nicer way to do it than zip + throw + catch? I kept searching rxjs docs but found nothing.

Code:

```
public getData(): Observable<Data> {
  return Observable.zip(
    this.userService.getCurrentUser(),
    this.authHttp.get(this.adminUrl),
    (user, adminResponse) => {
      if (user.role == 'admin') {
        return adminResponse.json() as BackendResponse
      } else {
        throw "You are not an admin";
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return Observable.zip(
        this.userService.getCurrentUser(),
        this.authHttp.get(this.normalUrl),
        (user, normalResponse) => {
          if (user.role == 'normal') {
            return normalResponse.json() as BackendResponse
          } else {
            throw "You are not allowed to get this resource";
          }
        })
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return Observable.throw(error)
    });
}
```

Admin endpoint returns some data for both admin and normal user (necessary in my project), but a standard user can get more data if they queries their special API.

Comment: The server should be rejecting any unauthorized requests.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that will work. We have a first observable user$ that returns data about the user and flag is user is admin. The second observable auth$ use this information to create a request with correct path and zip that takes data from the two observables and combine them.

```
const user$ = Observable.of({name:'julia', isAdmin})
    .publishLast()
    .refCount();

const auth$ = user$
.switchMap(user => 
    Observable.of(`${this.baseurl}${user.isAdmin ? 'adminPath' 
                                                 :'normalpath'}`));

Observable.zip(user$, auth$, 
     (x,y) =>  `user is ${JSON.stringify(x)} and auth is ${y}`)
     .subscribe(result =>  this.result = result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking if the user is in the correct role, and throwing a client side exception if they are not is definitely wrong. If your server is allowing the access to succeed then you have a critical security bug. If your server is correctly blocking the access, than all of your checks are confusing and pointless.

Also, catching and rethrowing exceptions like that is completely pointless and leads to redundant and convoluted code. Just let the error surface.

Given that, all you should need is something like

```
export default class {
  constructor(readonly authHttp: AuthHttp) { }

  get urls() {
    return {
      admin: this.adminUrl,
      normal: this.normalUrl
    };
  }

  getData(): Observable<BackendResponse> {
    return this.userService.getCurrentUser()
      .flatMap(user => this.authHttp.get(this.urls[user.role]))
      .map(response => response.json() as BackendResponse);
  }
}
```